# How to use injected services in static methods

Tags: angularjs, typescript, static-methods, inject

I want to use angularjs and typescript together. 
I'm trying to create `Orm factory` with typescript and stacked with some problem.

I defined my factory class as:

```
class OrmModel implements IOrmModel {
    static $inject = ['$http', '$q', 'config'];

    private name:string;
    private isNewRecord:boolean = false;

    constructor(public $http:ng.IHttpService, private $q:ng.IQService, private config:Object) {
        //...
    }

    static findAll(params:ISearchParams, relations:string[]):ng.IPromise<OrmModel> {
        //...
    }
}
```

Here I defined factory.

```
OrmModule:ng.IModel = angular.module('core.orm', []);
OrmModule.factory('OrmModel', ['$http', '$q', OrmModel]);
```

How can I use `$http` or `$q` in `findAll()` method?

Comment: Notice: with a class, you should use `myModule.service('OrmModel', OrmModel)`.

Comment: Using a dependency from a static function is a bad idea. However, you can declare a static variable `private static $http;`, then, in the constructor, do : `OrmModel.$http = $http;`

Comment: I think, I should use `service` like this `myModule.service('OrmModel', new OrmModel())`, because services in angular most of all are singletons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To live in the angular ecosystem singletons should be services. So move the `findAll` function into its own service. That way it can have access to other services like `$http` and `$q`.

Comment: You don't recommend working with singletones even if we are coding typescript? Isn't there any way to get access to injected parameter while working with typescript singletones?